# TYPO3 tx_news: Image for related News

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news

i'm trying to output just one image for related news.

Right now i'm using this

```
<f:render partial="Detail/MediaContainer" arguments="{media: related.media, settings:settings}" />
```

With this method i get all images from the news record. How can i get just one image, preferably just the one which is marked with "just show in listview".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using `related.mediaPreviews` instead of `related.media`.